# BASH: determine which of three strings is in a file

Tags: bash

I need to determine which of three strings is found in a file. It is guaranteed that only one of the three is found in the file. Then I want to do a different thing based on which of the three is in the file.

I am currently trying to do:

```
myfile="/home/directory/file.xml"
case "stringOne" in
    *$myfile*)
    #Do thing A
    ;;
esac
case "stringTwo" in
    *$myfile*)
    #Do thing B
    ;;
esac
case "stringThree" in
    *$myfile*)
    #Do thing C
    ;;
esac
```

however, this is not working, and my program gets stuck. Is there a better way, or a quick way to fix this way?

Comment: Can you use `grep` command?

Comment: So it sounds like you want to do `if stringOne in file; then do thing A; elif stringTwo in file; then do thing B; elif stringThree in file; then do thing C; fi`.  Is that it?  (If so, this is the beginning of the if/then/elif syntax I suspect you'll want.)

Comment: @blue if I use it, I get either the line where the file is - which I don't care about because all I want to know is if the line is in the file at all - or no output at all if the string is not in the file. I'm not sure how using `grep` would help.

Comment: Also you'll want to learn about `grep`'s `-s` option, and its exit status.

Comment: @steve could you show me what that would look like put together? I'm not entirely sure using `case` vs `if` is the problem

Comment: Something else you need to know is that when you write `if condition; then whatever; fi` in sh and bash, although the `condition` is _usually_ an invocation of the `test` command (or, equivalently, an expression in square brackets), you can actually put any command there, because what `if` looks at is the command's exit status.  If the command succeeds, the `if` branch is taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file is guaranteed to contain one of them, you can find which one it is and the use `case` statements:

```
myfile="/home/directory/file.xml"
str=$(grep -o -m 1 -E 'stringOne|stringTwo|stringThree' $myfile)

[[ -z ${str} ]] && { echo "No match found!"; exit 1; }

case "${str}" in
    stringOne)
       #Do thing A
       ;;

    stringTwo)
       #Do thing B
       ;;

    stringThree)
       #Do thing C
       ;;

esac
```

`grep` options:

- `-o` will print only the matching word. So you know which word is there in the input file.
- `-m 1` will ensure it stops at first match. So it doesn't need to scan the rest of the file.
- `-E` is for regex match that match which is to match either one of the three strings.

Comment: Could you explain what the `str=$(grep ... )` line is doing?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file data once and then check each string's presence:

```
data=$(</home/directory/file.xml)

if [[ $data == *stringOne* ]]; then
   echo "process stringOne"
elif [[ $data == *stringTwo* ]]; then
   echo "process stringTwo"
elif [[ $data == *stringThree* ]]; then
   echo "process stringThree"
fi
```